# Returning NULL data values while using an SP_ExecuteSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I'm using an sp_executesql so I can be flexible with what I choose to return. I'm encountering a problem when attempted to return data where there is none.

Say for instance I'm attempting to find all rows where there is no owner assigned. Currently, my query is written as follows.

```
 if @owner <> ''
    Begin
        SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and owner LIKE ''%'+@owner+'%'''
    END
```

This allows for me to not have to select an owner. If I do, it will of course be included in my query.

Since I'm now attempting to add a line that would basically allow me to just bring back unassigned owners:

```
 if @owner = 'Unassigned'
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and owner IS NULL' 
END
```

However, when I'm doing this, it will bring back the entire list. Thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: post whole sql than can able to figture out

Comment: Could you print out @sql (instead of executing it) and post the result?  Even if you have to change the table names & field names?

Comment: I took out a lot of the other script that was unnecessary, but there are more IFs other than the two I posted. I did it this way for aesthetic purposes.

Comment: Are you searching for if owner = 'Unassigned' .... ELSE if owner <> '' .... (i had to remove @ because comment allows only one)

Comment: May be its entering in both conditions...owner = unassigned and owner is <> '' ???? and you have select owner = 'unassigned' and if owner = 'Unassigned'  ....they are differents capitalized and non capitalized

Comment: Use PRINT @sql for debuging

Comment: I believe it is. I think the issue ends up being how it reads the NULL value when the variable is 'Unassigned'

Comment: So when it returns the list for your `if @owner = 'Unassigned'...` it returns everything? You see both Null and non-null values for owner returned?

Answer (score 3):

IF you change your last line to `PRINT @sql` you will notice both conditions are there.  Try changing your code to this.

```
if @owner <> ''
Begin
    if @owner = 'Unassigned'
        SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and owner IS NULL'
    else
        SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and owner LIKE ''%'+@owner+'%'''
END
```

Comment: You were exactly right. I had written them as two different IF statements, whereas instead I should have done the above. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use option with [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + CASE ISNULL(@owner, '') 
                       WHEN '' THEN ''
                       WHEN 'Unassigned' THEN ' and owner IS NULL'
                       ELSE ' and owner LIKE ''%' + @owner + '%''' END
```